# Getting parameters from query string

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, knockout.js

I am creating a web page using ASP.Net WebAPi, MVC and Knockout.

I have a normal MVC controller that loads the pages when I need them:

```
 [Authorize]
    public class AdminController : Controller
    {
        public ActionResult Clients()
        {
            return View();
        }

        public ActionResult ClientEdit(int? Id)
        {
            return View();
        }
    }
```

And once the page is loaded, my Knockout model takes care of the loading of the data. So, the 'Clients' controller simply loads a list of all clients. When on that screen, a user can click 'Edit' next to a client, and the page is navigated to the 'ClientEdit' controller, which takes an id.

So, my knockout click event looks like this in my knockout view model:

```
self.EditClick = function () {
        if (this.ClientId && typeof this.ClientId !== 'undefined') {
            window.location.href = "/Admin/ClientEdit/" + this.ClientId;
        }
        else
            window.location.href = "/Admin/ClientEdit/";
    }
```

(It handles the 'Create New' button and the edit button, hence the 'if')

Once I redirect, the MVC controller loads the page, and the URL is:

> http://localhost:49389/Admin/ClientEdit/1

I then load the knockout model, and would like to make an API call to get the data...

After my page loads, I want to bind the view model to the page. Here's my view model at the moment:

```
function AdminClientEditor() {
    var self = this;

    self.Name = ko.observable("");
    self.ContactName = ko.observable("");

ko.applyBindings(new AdminClientEditor(), $("#clienteditor")[0]);
```

So, I will create a $.get method that calls a webAPI method that will return me data based on the id. I just need to get the ID somehow.

But, how do I get the Id (In this case, '1', from the URL? 
And, is this the right way to achieve what I am trying to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've come up with this solution which works, but I am unsure if it's the best way. It seems pretty good.

I created a MVC ViewModel class in my application code, called 'GenericParameteModel', which at the moment, has a single parameter, "Id".

I then modified my page loading MVC method:

```
public ActionResult ClientEdit(int? Id)
{
     var mv = new GenericParameteModel { Id = Id };
     return View(mv);
}
```

On my View page, I added the model `'GenericParameteModel'` to the View.

I created a hidden field, called `'ClientId'` on the view.

```
<input type="hidden" id="clientId" value="@model.Id">
```

Then, within my knockout view model, I check if $("#clientId").val() has a value. If so, I do the $.get call, using that value, and populate my view model.

In doing so, all my initial page loads from MVC will have the ability to you the GenericParameteModel, and it will be a pattern for other pages. As it's a model, I can add new fields as my application requires.

This seems to work well. I'm unsure if this is an acceptable way as I am new to this (MVC to load views and the Knockout/WebApi to get the data after loading). But it seems neat and manageable.

Answer (score 2):

You can pass the id value to view via viewbag.

```
public ActionResult ClientEdit(int? Id)
{
     ViewBag.ClientId=id;
     return View();
}
```

and in the view's script section

```
var clientId="@ViewBag.ClientId";
alert(clientId);
// use this
```

If your javascript code which accesses this id value is inside a separate external js file, you may set this value to a js variable in your view and access it in your js file. Make sure to use namespacing to avoid global variable overwriting value issues.

So in your view

```
<script>
    var myApp = myApp || {};  
    myApp.ClientId= "@ViewBag.ClientId";
</script>
<script src="~/Scripts/PageSpecificExternalJsFile.js"></script>
```

And in the `PageSpecificExternalJsFile.js` file,

```
var clientId=myApp.ClientId;
//use this as needed
```

Comment: That just alerts "@ViewBag.ClientId"

Comment: Is it inside a razor view ?

Comment: It's within the javascript knockout viewmodel. I've edited the post with that view model. The code needs to go in there. When I attempted your example, it simply alerted the code, as opposed to getting the id.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is the best way, but you can get the ID from the URL by using JS:

```
var id = GetID();

function GetID() {
  var href = location.href;
  var results = href.split("/");
  return results[results.length - 1];
}
```